# [Vue warn]: Invalid expression.Generated function body error

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a city drop down list using `Asp.Net MVC 5` with `Vue.js`.

In `Razor` I described an attribute change method like this:

```
v_on="change:selectedCity"
```

Here in vue script usage:

```
 /*** USER CREATE EDIT FORM ****/
        var vmSptsUserFrm = new Vue({
            el: "#spts_user_frm",
            data: {
                citytown: 'citytowns',
                citytowns: [{ text: 'Toronto', value: 'citytown1' },
                         { text: 'Orleans', value: 'citytown2' }]
            },
            methods:{
                selectedCity: function () {
                    alert();
                }
            },
            ready:function() {
                selectedCity();
            }

        });
```

But I am getting this error when application start.

> [Vue warn]: Invalid expression. Generated function body: 
>   scope.change:scope.selectedCity

What can I do for solve this?

Comment: If your question was answered please accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `v-on:click="nameFunction"`.